# Difference between ToString("N2") and ToString("0.00")

Tags: c#, formatting

What is the difference between `ToString("N2")` and `ToString("0.00")`?

Comment: Can someone please look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77309614/2856597 It's NOT just a matter of formatting with/without thousand places.

Answer (score 42):

From [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

> The number is converted to a string of
>   the form "-d,ddd,ddd.ddd…", where '-'
>   indicates a negative number symbol if
>   required, 'd' indicates a digit (0-9),
>   ',' indicates a thousand separator
>   between number groups, and '.'
>   indicates a decimal point symbol.

It would seem that `N` will include thousands separators, whereas `0.00` will not.

See also [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 25):

**It's all about the decimal places**

`N2` will work the same way for 500.00, but when you have 5000.00, `N2` will display as

5,000.00

instead of

5000.00

See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: This can change according to the culture. In pt-BR, it would be 500,00 and 5.000,00

Answer (score 17):

Basically, `ToString("N2")` will use the `CultureInfo` to format the number. This means that your thousands separator might be different depending on the used `CultureInfo`. You can also pass the desired `CultureInfo` if you want.

Answer (score 11):

Both give you two decimal places, but you can see the difference easily if you check larger numbers:

```
var d = 1234567.89;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("N2") + "\t" + d.ToString("0.00"));
    d /= 10.0;
}
```

outputs

```
1.234.567,89    1234567,89
123.456,79  123456,79
12.345,68   12345,68
1.234,57    1234,57
123,46  123,46
12,35   12,35
1,23    1,23
0,12    0,12
0,01    0,01
0,00    0,00
```

[Execute code online at dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5a31tD)

Answer (score 3):

The thousand separator is an issue.  Using "n2" will give you  3,543 where using "0.00" will give you 3543.  The comma can break down-stream code that might have to parse that value back to a decimal, especially client-side js.

Comment: Actually "N2" will print "3,543.00".

Answer (score -8):

Here is example to explain

```
int rupees=567.3423;
string rp=rupees.tostring("N2");
```

--Answer is `rp="567.34";`
   -- N2 gives upto two decimal records.

Comment: The question asked the difference between `ToString("N2")` and `ToString("0.00")`, which isn't covered in this answer. Besides that, the answer is just straight up wrong since `N2`, as explained by the other answers, will keep `CultureInfo` in mind and will add a thousands separators.

Comment: either way, an int can't have a decimal place