# Bind textbox to float value. Unable to input dot / comma

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I try to input a DOT or a COMMA in a textbox, for example `1.02` or `83,33` the textbox prevents me to input such a value (and the input turns red). The textbox is bound to a float property. Why?

I have bound a textbox to a float Property `Power` of a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
private float _power;

public float Power
{
    get { return _power; }
    set
    {
        _power = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Power");
    }
}
```

In Xaml

```
<TextBox Name="txtPower" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Power, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

I have no custom validation at all right now.

Also tried decimal but it does not work either. For string everything works fine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try adding a StringFormat definition to the binding.
Like so:

```
<TextBox Name="txtPower" Height="23" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Power, Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat=N2}"></TextBox>
```

Comment: I used StringFormat={}{##.##} and this works for me. Not sure whats N2. Thanks!

Comment: @LukeSolar here is a answer for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506323/difference-between-tostringn2-and-tostring0-00

Comment: While this resolve the issue of entering something like 1.1, it adds multiple issues such as number is always displayed with decimals (i.e 1 is shows as 1.00), using backspace or delete keys in box will not work for some reason.  Placing cursor befor dot, then typing .11 results in 1.11.11

Comment: @pixel I experience the same behavior and IHMO this is unuseable. Did you find any solution to this, except changing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus` ?

Comment: For anyone struggling with the `StringFormat` if you need `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` a possible workaround is to bind to a `string` property and then validating that string inside the setter. You can also logically connect it to a `float`, `double`, or `decimal` property, so both values will syncronize.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Sorry, dont remember any more, was long time ago and I believe someone else looked at the issue

Comment: Oddly enough, with added `StringFormat` the textbox initially is empty. When I remove StringFormat it correctly shows its initial value (initial value is round one, "1", no decimal points);

Answer (score 32):

If you have .NET 4.5 or newer, you may enforce the pre 4.5 behaviour

```
System.Windows.FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
```

See [Sebastian Lux's blog](http://www.sebastianlux.net/2014/06/21/binding-float-values-to-a-net-4-5-wpf-textbox-using-updatesourcetriggerpropertychanged/):
With .NET 4.5 it is no longer possible to enter a separator character (comma or dot) with `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged` by default. Microsoft says, this intended.

Comment: The link is broken, which of course is why you shouldn't provide link-only answers.

Comment: @A.R. This is the full contained answer. Just one line of code. The link is just for credits.

Comment: It just suggests "try this" meaning it may not work.  No explanation, no context. just a broken link.  If you think the one liner does it all, at least make an edit an remove the broken link.

Comment: just a note that this will affect all textboxes. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92ae5178-4a92-4784-b30b-226ecb1eb146/decimal-binding-issue-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

to fix dot and comma issue in textbox binding to decimal or float

```
1-  UpdateSourceTrigger = LostFocus 
2-  add string format StringFormat={}{0:#.##} to escape unneeded zeros 


<TextBox Name="txtPower" Height="23" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Power, Mode=TwoWay, 
         UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus ,StringFormat={}{0:#.##}}"></TextBox>
```