# C#: print array to console line while rounding

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I used stackoverflow answers to figure out how to print my array to a single console line like this:

```
console.writeline(string.Join(",  ",myArray));
```

My array is decimal values (it is a double array) though and it prints very ugly.

Is there a way to round my array values inside this command?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myArray.Select(x => Math.Round(x, 2))));
```

It will round all values of `myArray` to two decimal places

Comment: Also, the [Math.Round Method (Decimal, Int32, MidpointRounding)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131275(v=vs.110).aspx) is available for when "banker's rounding" is not the desired method.

Answer (score 1):

A quickly way to do this is using linq or fluent syntax...
The example above rounded by 2 decimal places...

```
console.writeline(string.Join(",  ",myArray.Select(q => Math.Round(q, 2)).ToList()));
```

Comment: I was going to recommend  `"{0:N2}"` as the format.  Here is a question on the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506323/difference-between-tostringn2-and-tostring0-00

Comment: Does that *round* the numbers per se, or is it just printing the first two digits after the decimal point? That would usually be considered the "floor", which is perhaps one way of rounding numbers, but is probably not what people normally think of as rounding.

Comment: @Eilon Tested it. `"{0:N2}"` and `"{0:0.00}"` both appear to round the decimal places.

Comment: @JaredStroeb according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx it doesn't round, it just stops printing digits after some amount...

Comment: @JaredStroeb oh actually I may have spoken too soon. The MSDN docs are rather confusing here. Some formats do round, some do not. So this might actually be correct, my apologies.

Comment: Yes, you guys'r right. This way just format the value, for rounding the path for the success is Math.Round. Sorry for my misunderstood. :)