# How to format a string representation of a double to show 2 fractional digits

Tags: c#

I want to print a double as string, in a way that it allways shows 2 fractional digits, even if they are "00".

The expected output is 30.00 
but the actual result is 30.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        short a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        double d = (double)(a + b);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: so whats the actual issue here?

Comment: `int` is implicity convertible to `double` i think

Comment: following should work: `double d = (a + b);`

Comment: You already did... done. try `d.GetType()` it will tell you `d` is a double

Comment: why would you *want* to add a `short` and an `int` to get a `double`? absolute worst case would be a `long`, but frankly `int` will probably be fine...

Comment: @Niru can you describe not working?

Comment: ts not working man!!! actually the output should come like 30.00 but instead of that it displays **** 30.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

As the problem was not the "converting" from int/short to double, but the formatting of the resulting string, when printing i updated the Answer.

---

There is no need to explicitly Cast/Convert an Int/Short into Double. That is implicitly done.

Implicit Cast works like shown below:

```
  int i = 3;
  double d = i;
```

Working example of your code:
There is no need for an explicit cast.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        short a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        double d = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine( d.ToString("0.00"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result of the code above]

Or you could use [Convert.ToDouble()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ayes1wa5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
Example usage:

```
  int i = 3;
  double x = Convert.ToDouble(i);
```

Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) for further explanation.

### Update 2

Thanks to [Rand Random](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598770/rand-random) for the following hint.

You can also use `d.ToString("N2")`, that way you get thousand separators.

For further Information about the difference of "0.00" and "N2" have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506323/difference-between-tostringn2-and-tostring0-00) post.

Comment: i tried ya i dint get output like 30.00

Comment: could use "N2" instead of "0.00" and you will get a thousand seperator

Comment: @RandRandom thanks for the hint. I have included that in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just Change this line

```
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

To this

```
Console.WriteLine( d.ToString("0.00"));
```

This should work and will get output as 30.00.
It makes use of [formatting the string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/magazine/shxtf045(v=vs.95).aspx) by the given format provider.