# C# Formatting Floating Point Rounding/Accuracy Issue: N2 vs 0.00

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision

In C# (.Net 7):

```
float a = 13082987520.00f;
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine($"{a:N2}");
Console.WriteLine($"{a:0.00}");
```

I get:

```
1.3082988E+10
13,082,987,520.00
13082990000.00
```

In particular, notice the numerical difference between the last two lines:

```
13082987520
vs
13082990000
```

It's causing a lot of confusion when I try to write such numbers as CSV files.
In this expected behaviour?
How can we explain it?

Notice this question is VERY DIFFERENT FROM [Difference between ToString("N2") and ToString("0.00")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506323/difference-between-tostringn2-and-tostring0-00). I know the difference in terms of formatting, but here I am pointing out a potential unexpected implementation detail (and potentially a bug?) of floating point number printing. As shown in above case, apparently "N2" is NOT JUST adding thousand separators while "0.00" won't.

The same problem doesn't exist for double:

```
double b = 13082987520.00;
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.WriteLine($"{b:N2}");
Console.WriteLine($"{b:0.00}");
```

```
13082987520
13,082,987,520.00
13082987520.00
```

The question here is:

1. Which is the "correct" one for (single) floating point? (Actually it's the one printed with "N2")
2. How do I print the correct one (which is the one shown using "N2") without having to do `a.ToString("N2").Replace(",", string.Empty)`?

Comment: I think it's a bug or at least an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

From [ECMA-334:2022](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-334/) C# language standard, ch. 8.3.7:

> **Floating-point types**
>
> ...
>
> The `float` type can represent values ... with a precision of 7 digits.

(more on float point approximation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014) question, simply 32-bit IEEE float point numbers cannot provide more than 7 digits precision)

So both values are correct approximation, both values rounded to 7 digits provide equal rounded values:

```
13082987520

13082990000
      ^
      |
1234567
```

Float point numbers are good for approximate values. For exact values (hence e.g. for calculations on money) you should use `decimal` instead. From same standard ch. 8.3.8:

> The `decimal` type is a 128-bit data type suitable for financial and monetary calculations.

Comment: Well, that makes sense! I thought this only affects computing and didn't expect it affect formatting

Answer (score 2):

It's instructive to compare the behavior of the code running under .NET Framework 4.8.1 and .NET 7:

```
                                       // .NET FX 4.8.1     | .NET 7
Console.WriteLine(a);                  // 1.308299E+10      | 1.3082988E+10
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N2"));   // 13,082,990,000.00 | 13,082,987,520.00
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("0.00")); // 13082990000.00    | 13082990000.00
```

#### Which of these formatted values is correct?

Arguably, all of them are "correct". They agree with the value of `a` to seven decimal digits of precision, which is all that the `float` data type promises to support.

#### Why are the formatted values different between .NET Framework and .NET 7?

[.NET Core 3.0 improved the floating-point formatting code](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) to make it compliant with the [IEEE 754-2008 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008_revision). `ToString()` now returns the shortest round-trippable string, whereas `ToString("N2")` returns all digits available in the exact floating-point value.

#### In .NET 7, why do custom format strings like "0.00" round `float` values after seven digits?

Apparently, [this behavior is for backward compatibility](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Number.Formatting.cs,269):

```
// SinglePrecisionCustomFormat and DoublePrecisionCustomFormat are used to ensure that
// custom format strings return the same string as in previous releases when the format
// would return x digits or less (where x is the value of the corresponding constant).
private const int SinglePrecisionCustomFormat = 7;
```

#### How can I obtain the same value as "N2" but without commas?

Try using the "F2" fixed-point format instead:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{a:F2}"); // 13082987520.00
```

Comment: That's very helpful with plenty of insights! Thanks for pointing out `F2` formatting option!